# Spring Security ant matcher for path and it's path variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm configuring a Spring Boot app that has 2 security entrypoints and I configured the first one which is a Basic Auth to match the ant pattern `/synchro/task/**`. But when I test it, it works when I try the URL with just `/synchro/task` but not when I get the task id such as `/synchro/task/1`.

My code is as below :

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .antMatcher("/synchro/task/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("APP")
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

I also tried to use `requestMatchers` and two `antmatchers` to match `/synchro/task/*` and `/synchro/task/**` but it only takes the `/synchro/task` but not when there is an id.

The fun fact is that when I set as below :

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .antMatcher("/synchro/task/*")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("APP")
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

It works but only with the `/synchro/task/1` for example but no more with the `/synchro/task`.

So how could I combine both even if I really thought that the `antMatcher("/synchro/task/**")` would cover both paths with ids and without.

Here is my controller class :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/synchro")
public class SynchroResource extends GenericResource {
    @Autowired
    private IndexationService indexationService;
    @Autowired
    private SynchroService synchroService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/task", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public IndexationTaskResponse getNextTask() {
        return this.indexationService.getNextTask();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/task/{taskId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateTaskState(@PathVariable long taskId,
                            @RequestBody(required = false) String errorMessage) {
        this.indexationService.updateTaskState(taskId, errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried "/synchro/task**" and still the same result the "/synchro/task" works but not the "/synchro/task/1" where 1 is an id does not work. When I should get a 401 when there is no Authorization I get a 200 instead.

Comment: @EzekielaRakotoarijaona `.antMatcher("/synchro/task/**")` is the right way, to match all sub paths. But the URL `/synchro/task` is not a sub path. It should work if you use the URL `/synchro/task/`. That's a workaround.

Comment: @EzekielaRakotoarijaona If you really need to match both paths, you should replace `.antMatcher("/synchro/task/**")` with `.requestMatchers().antMatchers(""/synchro/task"", "/synchro/task/**")`.

Comment: "Spring Boot app that has 2 security entrypoints"...what does it mean??

Comment: Is there any error? Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and paste the trace here

Comment: @dur your upvoted comment is the actual answer and helped me finally figure this out in my project. if you make an answer out of the comment i will upvote. unsure whether there is a question with more votes where you could also put it.

Answer (score 2):

`/synchro/task/**` matches only directories in the path `/synchro/task/`, see [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html):

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - ? matches one character
> - * matches zero or more characters
> - ** matches zero or more directories in a path
> - {spring:[a-z]+} matches the regexp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring"

But `/synchro/task` is not a directory in path `/synchro/task/`, so you need to add your parent `/synchro/task` directory.

Your modified code:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/synchro/task", "/synchro/task/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("APP")
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable();
    
http
    .antMatcher("/synchro/task/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/synchro/task/**").hasRole("APP")
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
```